# Sharing Custom JSTL Taglib Between Packages

Tags: maven, liferay, jstl, taglib

I have a number of Liferay portlet war projects that use common jstl tag libraries (c, fmt, fn, etc), and one custom lib.

For the time being, I've placed a copy of the tld's in each project's WEB-INF/tld folders.

```
project1
    src.main.webapp.WEB-INF.tld
        c.tld
        custom.tld
        fmt.tld
        ...
project2
    src.main.webapp.WEB-INF.tld
        c.tld
        custom.tld
        fn.tld
        ...
```

Occasionally we will make updates to our custom lib and this means updating all copies.

How can I create a dependency project that can hold all these tag libs for me?

Is it as simple as an empty project with a src/main/resources/WEB-INF/tld folder?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a working solution.

Create a new maven project, taglib-proj, packaging as jar.

Move the taglibs from project1 and project2 into taglib-proj

```
taglib-proj
  src.main.resorces
    tld
      c.tld
      custom.tld
      fmt.tld
      fn.tld
```

Refer to these taglibs from the web.xml of project1 and project2, using the resources folder as the location base.

```
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/tld/c.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>myCustomLib</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/tld/custom.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/tld/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fn</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/tld/fn.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    ...
</jsp-config>
```